# Why do we have both [hash] and [hashcode] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I got very confused asking a question about a hash function for making a non-prime hash table. Both of these tags exist and I can't figure out whether this is a good idea or not.

[hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashcode): A hash code is a result of applying a hash function to data, usually resulting in an integer.

[hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hash): A hash function is any well-defined procedure or mathematical function that converts a large amount of data into a small datum, usually a single integer. [snip lots of For X use Y]

These don't suggest a real difference to my mind, and a quick check of the top page doesn't reveal a difference to me either. I suppose somebody could have come along and told me I goofed up when I tagged my question with both, but that hasn't happened yet (it may happen) but at this point I question the ability do draw a distinction.

Is there a good reason?

Should we just merge [hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashcode) into [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hash)?

Should we expend enormous retag effort to make one cryptographic hash and one non-cryptographic hash? (I don't think so.)

Should we just ignore it?

Comment: I imagine these tags (supposed to?) imply some difference: hash is about implementing and using hash functions, where hashcode is more about usage of said function result (as in hashtables, optimisation of equality check, etc). Thus personally I don't like the idea of merging.

Comment: On the other hand, `hash` is a bit ambiguous. Wouldn't renaming it to something like `hash-functions` solve underlying problem?

Comment: @markalex: I'm not sure. What's the probability either one was used like that.

Comment: `hashing` is already synonymized to `hash` and I would vote to do the same with `hashcode`. Although I think `hashing` is a better tag name as it describes a *concept*.

Comment: hashcode has a very specific meaning and use in the Java language.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Doesn't mean there's a necessity for a special tag for it. The combination of "java" and "hashing" should be sufficient.

Comment: That would create ambiguity in the use of the tag, where “hashing” could refer to something different if paired or not with Java. Also, a java question could be about “regular” hashing operations, algorithms, etc; and not to the Java specifics of an object HashCode.

Comment: @yivi I don't see the problem with such ambiguity (in this particular case)

Comment: There are already the tags [tag:hash-function] and even [tag:cryptographic-hash-function]. What about using [tag:hash-function] for such cryptographic related hashing questions? Also "hashcode" related tags like [tag:hashcode] and [tag:gethashcode] can be synonyms for a new tag [tag:object-hashcode]. That way we can split the [tag:hash] questions into the two tags [tag:hash-function]/[tag:object-hashcode]. However, the problem might be that users enter only "hash" and will therefore select [tag:hash-function] (first hit?) even though they maybe meant to use [tag:object-hashcode].

Comment: @Progman: I have to admit I would have never found object-hashcode.